# Downgrade Ubuntu 12.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, system-installation

is there a way to downgrade Ubuntu 12.10 to 12.04 without any installation cds *AND WITHOUT LOSING ANY DATA.* Sorry for the caps, some people miss the improtant part. Also I know an alternate cd would work but they don't make them for newer Ubuntu releases so if I need to do this with 14.10-14.04 I'll be prepared.

Comment: By the very nature of downgrading you will lose some data. You will lose data describing 12.10 package tree for example. It is akin to asking if you can empty the trash on your computer without losing ANY data. The answer is: Of course, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no way to roll back to a previous install. You can download and create a bootable USB, and then replace your 12.10 with a 12.04 LTS install leaving your **user data** untouched. Of course, 12.04 is different from 12.10, so you'll have to lose the data that makes 12.10 different from 12.04. You would also have to re-install any applications you'd added to the base 12.10, but that's not difficult.

You really need to make a reliable backup of all your user data first, even if the re-install won't touch it, because stuff happens.